# What is the best way to file patent

Tags: pct, filling, non-provesional

What is the best way to file a US patent Provisional or non-provisional or PCT?
We have developed novel materials and examined their utilization in the real application as well as have all evidence.

Comment: You might want to expand the question. As it is, the answer is engage a patent attorney or agent professional to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Engage a patent attorney or patent agent to help you who is familiar with the general technology area and has good references.

Comment: While this is not the cheapest way to file a patent, it is almost always the best way.